# How to use plot model in keras?

Tags: python, keras, plotting, jupyter

I'm trying to draw the keras model with the plotmodel.

#### Setup:

I installed graphviz binaries with:

```
choco install graphviz
```

added path to the bin folder, and then I did:

```
pip install pydotplus
pip install graphviz
```

#### Code:

Getting this error when I try to execute:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

#### Error:

> ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.

Can someone suggest some alternative to draw the keras model? I need to implement this for a CNN.

Comment: Did you install them for the correct python interpreter your code is running for? If you are using python 3.x as interpreter for the code and using `pip install` to install for package, it will installed for Python 2.x.

Comment: I am using python 3.x for keras 2, i wanted to install for python 3. I tried conda install too, even that gives same error

Comment: Try `sudo pip3 install <package>`.

Comment: pip3 install doesnt work on my anaconda

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you have already done, in my notebook I added two lines:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632486/dot-exe-not-found-in-path-pydot-on-python-windows-7))

Comment: could someone tell me the correct way to reference other stack exchange posts in an answer